# Gnome Classic in 12.04 gives black screen

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

I have Gnome Classic installed from my 11.10 install. Whenever I try to boot into it on 12.04 beta, it gives me a black screen and does not load. Is there a way to see what is going on that it doesn't want to load? I really want to give classic a try.

Comment: Did you install Gnome Classic from a PPA?

Comment: I don't quite remember...it's been a while. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Type `synaptic` from the command line.  A GUI should pop up; on the left you can select a button "Origin".  You should then see in the left pane a list of repositories, including any PPAs you've added.  Click on a PPA and you can see in the right pane the list of packages installed from it.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's the problem, since gnome-session-fallback has been available for quite a while.  But worth verifying that you didn't install it some other way.  My other thought is you didn't mention if you had uninstalled anything, e.g. compiz.  I think there should also be another session option called "Gnome Session (no effects)"; what happens if you try that one?

Comment: Gnome Session (no effects) did the trick! .facepalm. I still cant get the normal gnome session to work....oh well. I do have compiz installed.

Comment: This suggests there's something wrong with your Compiz configuration.  Are you able to log into Unity?

Comment: Yes. Every other DE (Ubuntu 2D/3D, Gnome 3) works

Comment: Hi Ryan.  Have you tried removing `gnome-session-fallback` and re-installing it?

Comment: I gave that a try, even purged `gnome-session-fallback` and it's still black. I'm not too sure what is going on. I can get no effects to work, so I can be content with that for now.

Comment: Here's another possibility: in Gnome Classic (no effects), open CCSM and disable the Unity plugin.  Then see if you can login to regular Gnome Classic (but then you won't be able to log into some of your other DEs like your Ubuntu 3D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiz with gnome classic on 12.04 is extremely buggy. For starters it takes a very long time to load (it shows a black screen for nearly a minute.) Perhaps you just needed to wait a bit longer?

In any case, once it does load there are lots more bugs, graphical and otherwise. All of these bugs are caused by compiz 0.9.x. The only sensible way to use gnome-panel with compiz is to downgrade compiz to 0.8.x, though this will mean you cannot use Unity on the same machine.

It's also possible to enable metacity compositing in Gnome Classic (no effects) by using gconf-editor to set "/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager" and "/apps/metacity/general/compositor_effects" to True. However, this does not give you everything that you get from compiz.

Comment: "downgrade compiz to 0.8x" ... interesting - how do you do that? - adding that info will make this a great answer :)

Comment: Well, it involves purging compiz (and therefore Unity) and then installing it from source...

Comment: I waited about 2 minutes and it loaded, no problems. :) Patience is a virtue, that's for sure.